# Unable to run Ionic 4 app using cordova after installing Firebase X

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am running my Ionic 4 app using `ionic cordova run android`, & it builds & works fine on my device.

However, now I'm trying to install [Firebase X](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x) by running:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x
```

Then I add this to my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { FirebaseX } from '@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx';

providers: [
    FirebaseX,
]
```

After only making these changes, I run `ionic cordova run android`, but it fails & the following is logged to the console:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:   The number of method references in a .dex file
>   >     cannot exceed 64K.   Learn how to resolve this issue at
>   >     https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
> - Try:37 actionable tasks: 37 executed
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
>   insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 25s
>   C:\Users\damie\Documents\Ionic\my-mechanic\platforms\android\gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files
>   use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: C:\Users\damie\Documents\Ionic\my-mechanic\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java
>   uses  unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 119442 > 65536)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:   The number of method references in a .dex file
>   >     cannot exceed 64K.   Learn how to resolve this issue at
>   >     https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Also, below is my `ionic info output`:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\damie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Below is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.10.3'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Sets the maxSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMaxSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMaxSdkVersion = null
    }
    // The value for android.targetSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvTargetSdkVersion')) {
        cdvTargetSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-firebasex/starter-build.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras1 = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras1) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

def hasBuildExtras2 = file('../build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras2) {
    apply from: '../build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = cdvCompileSdkVersion == null ? (
    defaultCompileSdkVersion == null 
        ? privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
        : defaultCompileSdkVersion 
) : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvCompileSdkVersion);

if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    //ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = project.ext.defaultBuildToolsVersion
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();

// minSdkVersion, maxSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? defaultMinSdkVersion : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
    ext.cdvMaxSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
}
ext.cdvTargetSdkVersion = cdvTargetSdkVersion == null ? defaultTargetSdkVersion  : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvTargetSdkVersion)

ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps {
    doLast {
        println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
        println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
        println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
        println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
        println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
        println('cdvMaxSdkVersion=' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
        println('cdvTargetSdkVersion=' + cdvTargetSdkVersion)
        println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
        println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
        println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
        android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
            println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
        }
    }
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            // minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
            minSdkVersion 19
        }

        if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
            maxSdkVersion cdvMaxSdkVersion
        }

        if(cdvTargetSdkVersion != null) {
            // targetSdkVersion cdvTargetSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion 28
        }

// added this too
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    // This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    // By default, we multiply the existing version code in the
    // Android Manifest by 10 and add a number for each architecture.
    // If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    // ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }

    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
      if(['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release', 'validateSigningX76Release'].contains(task.name)) {
         promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
      }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

Comment: Add ur build.gradle file

Comment: Hi @PeterHaddad I've added it above. I've since made some changes based on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex, & I think that may have resolved it. I'm testing the app now to confirm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to upgrade the `minSdkVersion`, from the docs:

> If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you do not need the multidex support library.

Therefore update it to version 21

To do that, go to config.xml at the root of your project and change line

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

to

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
```